# Prove that this sequence converges.

Tags: limits

Given that $x_n\geqslant 0$, $x_{n+1}\leqslant x_n+\dfrac{1}{n^2}$, prove this sequence converges.

I want to prove by The monotone bounded convergence theorem.

$$
0\leqslant x_n=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)\leqslant\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{i^2}<\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}
$$
My question is how to prove the sequence is monotonous.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/895856/42969.

Comment: By the way, there is no reason for $(x_n)$ to be monotonic... (it can even be decreasing)

Comment: The duplicate targets were found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x_%7Bn%2B1%7D%5Cleqslant%20x_n%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D%24).