# Prove $\{x_n\}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is non-negative and satisfies $$x_{n+1}\le x_n+\frac{1}{n^2}$$
>   Prove $\{x_n\}$ converges.

My try:  I want to use Cauchy Test at first to state $|x_{n+p}-x_n|\lt \epsilon $ for $n\gt N$ and $p\gt 0$. Because I tried to claim  that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\le \frac{1}{n^2} $ for all $n$. But actually it may also holds $x_{n+1}-x_n\le-\frac{1}{n^2}$. Also I tried monotonous and bounded. But I can only prove it's bounded. What else can I do? Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Hint 1: telescoping the sequence, i.e. $x_n = x_1 + \sum_1^{n-1} (x_{j+1} - x_j) $. Hint 2: $1/n^2 < 1/(n(n-1))$.

Comment: Hint 2: Use hint 1 to prove that the $x_n$ is bounded from above.

Comment: @xbh  Yes, I already got this to prove it is bounded. But I am in trouble to get the next step. This sequence may not be monotonous.

Comment: Hint: a sequence of real numbers that is bounded has a limit point $L$, that means there exists a subsequence of indices $i_k$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty}x_{i_k} = L$. Using the inequality you are given, prove that actually the complete sequence converges to $L$, using $\epsilon - \delta$ arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Let
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Then
$$x_{n+1}-S_{n+1} \leq x_n -S_n$$

Define 
$$y_n =x_n-S_n$$

Then, $y_n$ is non-increasing and bounded from below (as $x_n \geq 0$ and $S_n$ increasing and convergent), therefore:

Comment: There is no absolute value in the given inequality. Could be $x_{1000} = x_{999} - 10^7$.

Comment: @Ingix Ty, fixed it now.

Comment: Sorry , I don't  understand why $x_{n+1}+S_{n+1}\le x_n+S_n$.  i.e $x_{n+1}\le x_n -\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: @LOIS Sorry wrong sign.