# Mathematical Analysis, Sequences, Limits, Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $x_{n}$ is a sequence of nonnegative real numbers satisfying $x_{n+1}\le x_{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ for all $n\ge 1$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}$ exists.

My idea was that $x_{n+1}-x_{n}<\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and from this point I can conclude that by telescoping series if exist $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}$ is bounded by using the right side but I could not conclude the existence of limit exactly. I will appreciate if you help. Although this seems easy question I could not find the exact idea becuase $(x_{n+1}-x_{n})$ does not need to be positive.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles

Comment: Remember that the real numbers form a complete set so Cauchy sequences converge.

Comment: @JohnDouma Note there is a difficulty in that we don't know what $|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ looks like, only what $x_{n+1}-x_n$ looks like

Comment: Here is another answer to your [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/185989/121671). To avoid posting duplicates, the site https://approach0.xyz/ is very useful.

Comment: @Mittens this question is different as $x_n$ is nonnegative

Comment: @Tim: look then at this other [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/185989/121671).

Comment: @Mittens Yes, I think this answer the question. Anyway, it is nice to see FShrike answer.

Comment: It happens too often that I answer a question in good faith and it turns out the OP did not want to check if the question had been already answered first. I've posted my answer to one of the duplicates now @Tim

Comment: I was trying to understand it where did you post could you send me a link?